# document.location re-direct looping

Tags: javascript

I have 3 different index.html-type pages for different screen sizes: index.html for > 1280, indexsm.html for <= 1024 and indexmed.html for <= 1280.

I thought I could get around this with the following JS:

```
if  (screen.width <= 1024)
{
  document.location = "indexsm.html"
}
else if (screen.width <= 1280)
{
  document.location = "indexmed.html"
}
else 
{
  document.location = "index.html"
}
```

Opening index.html on a screen 1024 or less, the redirect works perfectly and redirects to indexsm.html.
Opening index.html on a screen at 1280, the redirect works perfectly and opens indexmed.html.
Opening index.html on a screen at 1920 (for example), my jacascript loops and keeps reloading the index.html page endlessly.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I've searched for hours and have been unable to find the cure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this script is *in* `index.html`, why would you re-set the location (and therefore reload the page) at all?

```
if  (screen.width <= 1024) 
{
  document.location = "indexsm.html"
}
else if (screen.width <= 1280)
{
  document.location = "indexmed.html"
}

// else we're already where we need to be, so stop
```

Comment: That said, this is *not* a recommended or well-loved approach, for loads of reasons. Please, I beg you, look into [Responsive Design](https://responsivedesign.is/).

Comment: Thanks Paul. That works great. To answer your question as to why re-set location: I guess just simply because I'm not very good at this. RE: Responsive Design, thanks for that info. I'm just doing this to help a friend for free and do not want to learn about responsive design and flex grids. If my friend is so inclined or has issues with the way this turns out, he is free to pay the designer of his choice. If that's the case, I'll pass along your info ;) .... thanks again. Cheers.

Comment: ...but I can sure see where you are coming from; IE & Safari do not seem to like this code. Maybe responsive is worth a peek. Thanks again Paul.